# SharePoint RSS Feed Redirect

Tags: redirect, sharepoint-2010, rss

Currently I've set up an internal SharePoint (2010) to create an RSS feed for various updates/announcements for our department.

As the section of our system that has the official updates/announcements does not allow RSS feeds, we are currently manually updating the SharePoint every morning.

One of the feedback suggestions I've received is a that, for the official ones, when you click on the RSS feed title, have it redirect to the official section, rather than SharePoint.

Just wondering if this is possible? Not looking for a solution to be completely provided, but a push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks.